# Low power when starting up Toyota Avalon

Tags: toyota, stall, avalon, iac-valve

My buddy owns a 2002 Toyota Avalon. When he starts it up it barely holds RPMs, and he has to give it gas when it starts up.

Linked video https://youtu.be/XTiK5BFFXKg

He thinks it might be the idle air control valve.

The starter, spark plugs and gasket valve seals and engine valve seals have been replaced.  Along with timing belt.

Is it the idle air control valve?